# Jfree chart change Y axis data

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, linechart

I am using Jfree chart 0.9.20's XYLineChartDemo for plotting the execution time of running processes in a program. My X axis denotes the time and Y axis should denote the Pid. How can I edit the Jfreechart files to make my Y axis to denote values I want and not numbers 0-range?? Also is there a way to make the line plotted to be made thicker in width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

study this:

```
public JFreeChart createChart(String axisX, String axisY){

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(null, axisX, axisY, dataSeries, true, true, false);

    final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0,true);
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, true);

    //percentage (y-axis)
    final NumberAxis percentAxis = new NumberAxis(axisY);
    percentAxis.setInverted(false);
    percentAxis.setRange(0.0, 100.0);

    //time (x-axis)
    final DateAxis timeAxis = new DateAxis(axisX);
    timeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(DateAxis.createStandardDateTickUnits(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.ENGLISH));

    double range = 0;

    switch (format){
        case ONE_MINUTE_RANGE: range = 60*1000; break;
        case TEN_MINUTE_RANGE: range = 10*60*1000; break;
        case ONE_HOUR_RANGE: range = 60*60*1000; break;
    }

    timeAxis.setRange(System.currentTimeMillis()-range/2, System.currentTimeMillis()+range/2); //time duration based on format chosen

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.setDomainAxis(timeAxis);
    plot.setRangeAxis(percentAxis);

    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.gray);
    plot.setRangeZeroBaselinePaint(Color.gray);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.gray);
    plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
    plot.setRenderer(renderer);

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    return chart;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have set the lower range to be my lowest pid and higher one to be the highest pid. Any pointers as to how to change width of the line in XY line chart?

Comment: @user644575 you should use ChartPanel container to change the width and height of your JFreeChart object

Comment: @user644575: For the series line stroke (where you call it as "width"), use `LineAndShapeRenderer.setSeriesStroke(int series, java.awt.Stroke stroke)` method to set the stroke.