# dynamic generation of jfree chart -pie chart

Tags: java, charts

is their a way that we can populate pie chart dynamically.... that based on the values got from database...can any one guide me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java graph or chart library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527640/java-graph-or-chart-library)

Comment: @Thilo: he's asking how to do it.  He's already using jFree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The value from db....may not be
>   fixed.....so.....the parameters...will
>   be varying........how to do?
>
> I am getting data from db....using
>   `ResultSet`

You can try something like this

```
    DefaultPieDataset pieDataSet = new DefaultPieDataset();

// select subject,value from datatable;
// rs will be your ResultSet

    while (rs.next()) {
        String sub = rs.getString(1);
        int val = rs.getInt(2);
        pieDataSet.setValue(sub, new Integer(val));
    }
```

If the value is not stored in integer format in the database then parse it using

```
    int val = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically update your dataset for any `JFreeChart` object (sorry if I don't use a Pie chart for an example, but you can figure it out):

Make sure your data from DB is populated into a `DataSet` object where it is part of a class field.

Create a class helper method that returns a `JFreeChart` which contains:

1. a `ChartFactory` method which creates
   a `JFreeChart` object
2. a plot object
3. any objects that allow chart and
   plot rendering, etc.

Pass this `DataSet` object to your `ChartFactory` method that relates to the type of chart you want

Call your class helper method from an event or something that allows the chart to be updated where it passes `JFreeChart` object to a `ChartPanel` object...

```
chartPanel.setChart(createChart(axisX, axisY));
```

If you want the chart to be updated in intervals, use a Timer-based object to update the code.

For an example of such helper method can be found in my other post:

[Jfree chart change Y axis data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281218/jfree-chart-change-y-axis-data/5281276#5281276)

Answer (score 1):

There are several jFreeChart samples on their site here:

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html

Comment: @jonah.....the value from db....may not be fixed.....so.....the parameters...will be varying........how to do?

Comment: @user654761: Just load the values like you normally would, and just substitute the static values in the pie chart for the database values.

Comment: @user654761: Not really.  Do you already have code to extract the data from the database?

Comment: hi....all i got solution just use...pieDataSet.setValue(Name, count);in resultset .....

Comment: @user654761: if your problem is solved, please click the green checkmark on the best answer.